# How can I find the index of the selected choice in a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

How do I access the SelectedIndex of an ActiveX combobox object in Excel? I need an integer.

Answer (score 28):

I think `combo.ListIndex` is the property you're looking for...

Comment: this didn't work for me, could not set the ListIndex property :(

Comment: It should be settable - have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196331(v=office.11).aspx If it's not, then there must be something else going wrong. I suggest posting a new question

Answer (score 7):

The .ListIndex property works if only one item is selected, however, you need to browse the .Selected collection if you allow multiple selections.