# Save data from multiple columns in combobox to available cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not a programmer for the profession, I'm a system administrator who usually brings together the puzzle when I try something. Now I would need help simplifying an Excel form to make it useful. It will be used by me.

I have a combobox that contains 4 columns. I also have a button. When you click the button, I want to save data from the four columns in my combobox to the next available row of cells starting from row 3. I want data to be saved only to row 30. I have tested back and forth but do not get it, so I've completely deleted the code. Any ideas?

Sheet named "Data"

[image: Worksheet("Data")]
[image]

I use ListFillRange in my ComBobox for the data source.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call SaveComboBoxData

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SaveComboBoxData()

End sub
```

Using ActiveX controls
ComboBox1
CommandButton1[image]

Comment: Why did you delete the code ? To get some help, you need to show something that people can work on. What exactly do you do : You get B14 to E14 as a value in the Combobox, then you put the chosen line number in a Cell like A24 ? From the little you say, there is only 1 choice in your Combobox ?

Comment: There was not much code. I added some information above.

Comment: So, you get Colomns B to E from 1 to 14, as a value each line in the ComboBox, is it ? If you can put a dummy file, that'll be much easier :)

Comment: I added a picture. I'm trying to fill the cells under the combobox.

Comment: I can put a dummy file here on monday If you are willing to take a look :)

Comment: you can't put a screen of the sheets with hidden values (if sensible) ? What are the rules you want to set in order to fill the cells ? Is there a link with any interaction on the combobox at all ?

Comment: Do you mean to output to E as your data in image goes from A:D?

Comment: I have rewritten the post. The pictures should explain it all.

Comment: Looks like you are creating a database. I would suggest using Access. Are you on Excel 2016? If so, you could use the data form functionality to add the records. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xitBuQinWcA

Comment: And why only to row 30? What happens at 30, do you start overwriting? Do you clear out all historic and start over, do you terminate? Also, is this a form control, an activex control? Is it in the sheet or on a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tidy this up further,

**Note:**

1. You appear to be building a database so consider the preferred option of using an [access database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-and-build-tables-for-a-database-access-basics-part-1-bff6e7b2-3055-419b-8751-1ade558ea31f) to store this data
2. If you have Excel 2016 you could be using [Data Entry Forms](http://www.contextures.com/exceldataentryupdateform.html) instead which are dead simple.
3. Assume using ActiveX combobox. You will need to alter this

   ```
   Set sourceCombo = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("Combobox1").Object
   ```

   if working with a form control.

### **Code for the type of operation you are describing:**

**Code pane for Order sheet:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    AddRecords
End Sub
```

**Standard module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRecords()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = wb.Worksheets("Order")
    Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim lastRowTarget As Long
    Dim sourceCombo As ComboBox

    Set sourceCombo = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("Combobox1").Object 'assume activex object

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim nextRow As Long

    With sourceCombo

        For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1

            If lRow = sourceCombo.ListIndex Then

                nextRow = GetNextRow(targetSheet)

                If nextRow = 31 Then

                    MsgBox "End row of 30 reached"
                    Exit Sub

                End If

                For lCol = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1

                   targetSheet.Cells(nextRow, lCol + 1) = .List(lRow, lCol)

                Next lCol

                Exit For

            End If

        Next lRow

    End With

End Sub

Private Function GetNextRow(targetSheet As Worksheet) As Long

    With targetSheet
         GetNextRow = IIf(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row < 3, 3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

**Code in action:**

[image: Running code]

**References:**

- [How to get selected value in multicolumn listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244444/how-to-get-selected-value-in-multicolumn-listbox)
- [How can I find the index of the selected choice in a combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593627/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-the-selected-choice-in-a-combobox)
- [How to create a data entry form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xitBuQinWcA)

Comment: Wonderful work. I will look at it on Monday. Greatest regards.