# Identifying the Index of a Selected Element in Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I wish I could get the index of the selected value in a userform combobox list.

I've tried the below, but it shows me the value itself, instead of the index position

```
MsgBox (Userform.Combobox.List(Userform.Combobox.ListIndex))
```

In the example below:

```
0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
```

If I select the value "B" in the userform combobox, I'd like to print the index 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593627/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-the-selected-choice-in-a-combobox

Comment: `.ListIndex` is the position you're looking for.  Unless there are multiple selections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I've tried the below, but it shows me the value itself, instead of the index position*
>
> ```
> MsgBox (Userform.Combobox.List(Userform.Combobox.ListIndex))
> ```

`UserForm.ComboBox.ListIndex` gives you the index.

`UserForm.ComboBox.List(index)` gives you the value at that index.

If you want just the index, don't get the value at that index:

```
MsgBox Userform.Combobox.ListIndex
```